# Membership Fixed period, early bird before membership year start

Tags: civimember

i am doing fixed period.
membership start date is May 1, 2019 membership end date is April 30, 2020
early bird starts April 1st
I have set the Fixed Period Start Day to be May 01
I have set the Fixed Period Rollover Day to be April 01

Have i got this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rollover means if i join on April 2nd i get ~ 13 months in the first year. so if that is what you mean by early bird then yes you should be sorted

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for the reply, that is what I understood too. Civi 5.9.0 on Joomla 3.9.3. The start date is one year off, so I get May 1st, 2018 to April 30th, 2020. Does it work better in Drupal? Any suggestions? I've set Early Bird to start March 1st, and did a registration today, March 1st.

Comment: Hope this helps make it clearer - the Fixed Period Start Day shows the wrong year. it should show May 1st 2019, and instead it shows May 1st 2018. This error can be seen in the confirmation email, and in the members contact record. The variable I think is is:  $mem_start_date. I'm wondering if a band-aid solution is to modify the following: Message Template - Memberships - Receipt (on-line). Right answer is to get the membership start date right.

Comment: I answered in your other Q. Note other's comments that it can annoy folk if you end up asking similar Q multiple time rather than editing / extending your original Q

Comment: and core civi is not affected by CMS in use